# MBR2GPT Powershell script pre-validation check

Tags: powershell, mbr2gpt

Before i get the lecture, i know...

But hear me out, then help me out!

I have put together a very basic powershell script (for the sake of this issue) to try and just simply run a pre-validation check, with the intentions of changing the write-host to further actions or exits depending on result of mbr2gpt validation:

```
$MBRVAL = (mbr2gpt /allowfullos /validate)
If($MBRVAL -like "NotSpecified: (Disk layout validation failed for disk 0"){
    write-host "Error in MBR Conversion"
}
else{
    write-host "Ready for Conversion"
}
```

Now if you ran MBR2GPT you may not get this Disk layout error (unless you've already done it per chance)

But the error is what you'd get if validation fails verbatim to results in Powershell if run on a machine with such error present in validation.

However, the 'like' / match / contains none of them work, and so it falls back to else consistently.

Now - the actual error is the application error, as a string.

```
mbr2gpt : Disk layout validation failed for disk 0
At line:1 char:12
+ $MBRVAL = (mbr2gpt /allowfullos /validate)

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Disk layout validation failed for disk 0:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

So, is this a something i can reference in my script as an IF statement or not, and if so, how?! :D

Answer (score 0):

Since MBR2GPT.EXE is a native command we need to check for errors by redirecting the error stream to the success stream by using `2>&1`.  If we do not add this [redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.1#powershell-redirection-operators) the errors will not be captured in the variable.

```
# Redirect error stream to success stream to also capture any errors
$MBRVAL = MBR2GPT.EXE /allowfullos /validate 2>&1

# Check if any error records exist and capture these in variable $errors
If ( $errors = $MBRVAL | Where-Object { $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] }  ) {
    # we found errors.  Check the exception message for specific error
    switch -regex ($errors.Exception.Message) {
        'Disk layout validation failed for disk' { 
            Write-Host 'Disk layout validation error in MBR Conversion' -ForegroundColor Red 
        }
        Default { Write-Host 'Some other error...' -ForegroundColor Red }
    }
}
# if no errors do the following
else {
    Write-Host 'Ready for Conversion' -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

---

Ok, so that was the overly complicated version if you need to do error handling based on the error.

If you don't care about what the error is you could take a more simple approach using [$LASTEXITCODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#lastexitcode)

```
MBR2GPT.EXE /allowfullos /validate
if ($LASTEXITCODE){    # or if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0){
    Write-Host "Some error occurred..." -ForegroundColor Red
} else {
    Write-Host "Success" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

If `$LASTEXITCODE` = anything other than 0 then an error occurred in the last native command run.  
You could also react to this [return code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt#return-codes) based on its value.

```
switch ($LASTEXITCODE) {
    0   { 'Conversion completed successfully.' }
    1   { 'Conversion was canceled by the user.' }
    2   { 'Conversion failed due to an internal error.' }
    3   { 'Conversion failed due to an initialization error.' }
    4   { 'Conversion failed due to invalid command-line parameters.' }
    5   { 'Conversion failed due to error reading the geometry and layout of the selected disk.' }
    6   { 'Conversion failed because one or more volumes on the disk is encrypted.' }
    7   { 'Conversion failed because the geometry and layout of the selected disk do not meet requirements.' }
    8   { 'Conversion failed due to error while creating the EFI system partition.' }
    9   { 'Conversion failed due to error installing boot files.' }
    10  { 'Conversion failed due to error while applying GPT layout.' }
    100 { 'Conversion to GPT layout succeeded, but some boot configuration data entries could not be restored.' }
    Default {'Undocumented error'}
}
```